# Static qt build messes up text

Tags: windows, qt, qt6

Built a static qt build and the resulting exes and program seem to have incorrectly rendered text.

The same config works fine in qt5 but fails in qt6.

Does anybody know the missing library?

[image: qt 6.3 rendering issue]

build config

```
Building for: win32-msvc (x86_64, CPU features: sse sse2)
Compiler: msvc 19.32.31332.0
Build options:
  Mode ................................... debug and release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Fully optimize release builds (-O3) .... no
  Building shared libraries .............. no
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++17
  Relocatable ............................ no
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    SSE .................................. SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    AVX .................................. AVX AVX2
    AVX512 ............................... F ER CD PF DQ BW VL IFMA VBMI
    Other x86 ............................ AES F16C RDRAND SHA
  Sanitizers:
    Addresses ............................ no
    Threads .............................. no
    Memory ............................... no
    Fuzzer (instrumentation only) ........ no
    Undefined ............................ no
  Build parts ............................ libs tools
  App store compliance ................... no
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt PrintSupport ........................ yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... no
  Zstandard support ...................... no
  Thread support ......................... yes
Common build options:
  Linker can resolve circular dependencies  yes
Qt Core:
  backtrace .............................. no
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  ICU .................................... no
  Using system libb2 ..................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  cpp/winrt base ......................... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  PCRE2 .................................. yes
    Using system PCRE2 ................... no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  Schannel ............................... yes
  OpenSSL ................................ no
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ no
  DTLS ................................... no
  OCSP-stapling .......................... no
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
  GSSAPI ................................. no
  Brotli Decompression Support ........... no
Core tools:
  Android deployment tool ................ yes
  macOS deployment tool .................. no
  Windows deployment tool ................ yes
  qmake .................................. yes
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ no
  HarfBuzz ............................... no
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ no
  Fontconfig ............................. no
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. no
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. no
      Using system libjpeg ............... no
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ no
  Text formats:
    HtmlParser ........................... yes
    CssParser ............................ yes
    OdfWriter ............................ yes
    MarkdownReader ....................... yes
      Using system libmd4c ............... no
    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... yes
    Dynamic OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. no
  libinput ............................... no
  HiRes wheel support in libinput ........ no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. no
    XCB Xlib ............................. no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ no
    xcb-sm ............................... no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... no
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... no
  VK_KHR_display ......................... no
  QNX:
    lgmon ................................ no
    IMF .................................. no
  XCB:
    Using system-provided xcb-xinput ..... no
    GL integrations:
      GLX Plugin ......................... no
        XCB GLX .......................... no
      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... no
  Windows:
    Direct 2D ............................ yes
    Direct 2D 1.1 ........................ yes
    DirectWrite .......................... yes
    DirectWrite 3 ........................ yes
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows WindowsVista
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... yes
  PostgreSQL ............................. no
  SQLite ................................. no
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
Further Image Formats:
  JasPer ................................. no
  MNG .................................... no
  TIFF ................................... yes
    Using system libtiff ................. no
  WEBP ................................... yes
    Using system libwebp ................. no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML just-in-time compiler .............. yes
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
Qt QML Models:
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  TreeView item .......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
  Calendar support ....................... yes
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Basic Fusion Imagine Material Universal macOS Windows
Qt Multimedia:
  GStreamer 1.0 .......................... no
  Video for Linux ........................ no
  Linux DMA buffer support ............... no
  MMRenderer ............................. no
  AVFoundation ........................... no
  Windows Media Foundation ............... yes
Qt 3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
  Use SSE2 instructions .................. yes
  Use AVX2 instructions .................. no
  Aspects:
    Render aspect ........................ yes
    Input aspect ......................... yes
    Logic aspect ......................... yes
    Animation aspect ..................... yes
    Extras aspect ........................ yes
Qt 3D APIs:
  Vulkan ................................. no
Qt 3D Renderers:
  OpenGL Renderer ........................ yes
  RHI Renderer ........................... yes
Qt3D Geometry Loaders:
  Autodesk FBX ........................... no
Qt 5 Compatibility Libraries:
  iconv .................................. no
Qt Charts Types:
  Area Chart ............................. yes
  Line Chart ............................. yes
  Spline Chart ........................... yes
  Scatter Chart .......................... yes
  Bar Chart .............................. yes
  Pie Chart .............................. yes
  Boxplot Chart .......................... yes
  Candlestick Chart ...................... yes
Qt Axis Types:
  DateTime Axis .......................... yes
Qt Tools:
  Qt Assistant ........................... no
  QDoc ................................... no
  Clang-based lupdate parser ............. no
  Qt Designer ............................ yes
  Qt Distance Field Generator ............ yes
  Qt Linguist ............................ yes
  pixeltool .............................. yes
  qdbus .................................. yes
  Qt Attributions Scanner ................ yes
  qtdiag ................................. yes
  qtplugininfo ........................... yes
Qt Opcua:
  Open62541 .............................. yes
  Unified Automation C++ SDK ............. no
  Support for namespace 0 NodeId names ... yes
  Namespace 0 NodeIds generator .......... no
  Open62541 security support ............. no
  Support for global discovery server .... no
Serial Port:
  ntddmodm ............................... yes
QtQuick3D:
  Assimp ................................. yes
  System Assimp .......................... no
Qt Remote Objects:
  High Availability Manager (ham) ........ no
Qt Scxml:
  ECMAScript data model for QtScxml ...... yes
Qt Sensors:
  WinRT sensors backend .................. yes
Qt SerialBus:
  Socket CAN ............................. no
  Socket CAN FD .......................... no
  SerialPort Support ..................... yes
Qt Virtualkeyboard:
  Desktop integration .................... yes
  Built-in layouts ....................... yes
  Key navigation ......................... no
  Retro style as default ................. no
  Sensitive Debug ........................ no
  Cerence ................................ no
    Static Linking ....................... no
    Handwriting .......................... no
      Alphabetic ......................... no
      CJK ................................ no
    XT9 .................................. no
      XT9 Debug .......................... no
      XT9 9-key layouts .................. no
    Bundle resources ..................... no
      Handwriting ........................ no
      XT9 ................................ no
  Hunspell ............................... no
    Using Hunspell copy from 3rdparty/ ... no
  OpenWnn ................................ yes
  MyScript ............................... no
  Language support enabled for:
    Arabic .......
........................ yes
    Bulgarian ............................ yes
    Czech ................................ yes
    Danish ............................... yes
    German ............................... yes
    Greek ................................ yes
    English GB ........................... yes
    English US ........................... yes
    Spanish .............................. yes
    Spanish Mexico ....................... yes
    Estonian ............................. yes
    Farsi ................................ yes
    Finnish .............................. yes
    French Canada ........................ yes
    French France ........................ yes
    Hebrew ............................... yes
    Hindi ................................ yes
    Croatian ............................. yes
    Hungarian ............................ yes
    Indonesian ........................... yes
    Italian .............................. yes
    Japanese ............................. yes
    KoreNote: Using static linking will disable the use of dynamically loaded plugins. Make sure to import all needed static plugins, or compile needed modules into the library.
Note: Hunspell in Qt Virtual Keyboard is not enabled. Spelling correction will not be available.

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.
Either set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
You will also need to set the FEATURE_clang CMake variable to ON to re-evaluate this check.
WARNING: Clang-based lupdate parser will not be available. LLVM and Clang C++ libraries have not been found.
You will need to set the FEATURE_clangcpp CMake variable to ON to re-evaluate this check.
WARNING: QtWebEngine won't be built. Statican ............................... yes
    Malay ................................ yes
    Norwegian ............................ yes
    Dutch ................................ yes
    Polish ............................... yes
    Portuguese Brazil .................... yes
    Portuguese Portugal .................. yes
    Romanian ............................. yes
    Russian .............................. yes
    Slovak ............................... yes
    Slovenian ............................ yes
    Albanian ............................. yes
    Serbian .............................. yes
    Swedish .............................. yes
    Thai ................................. yes
    Turkish .............................. yes
    Ukrainian ............................ yes
    Vietnamese ........................... yes
    Simplified Chinese ................... yes
    Traditional Chinese .................. yes
    HongKong Chinese ..................... no
  Traditional chinese input methods:
    Zhuyi build is not supported.
WARNING: QtPdf won't be built. node.js version 12 or later is required.

n ............................... yes
    Cangjie .............................. yes
WebEngine Repository Build Options:
  Build Ninja ............................ no
  Build Gn ............................... yes
  Jumbo Build ............................ yes
  Developer build ........................ no
  Build QtWebEngine Modules:
    Build QtWebEngineCore ................ no
    Build QtWebEngineWidgets ............. no
    Build QtWebEngineQuick ............... no
  Build QtPdf Modules:
    Build QtPdfWidgets ................... no
    Build QtPdfQuick ..................... no
  Qt 3rdparty libs:
    qtfreetype ........................... yes
    qtpng ................................ no
    qtpng ................................ yes
    qtjpeg ............................... no
    qtzlib ............................... yes

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Qt/6.3.1/Src
```

configure command

```
configure.bat -static -debug-and-release -prefix "C:\Qt\qt_special_static" -platform win32-msvc -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -opengl desktop -no-openssl -no-sql-sqlite -no-harfbuzz -no-gif -no-libjpeg -opensource -confirm-license -make libs -nomake tools -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

Comment: Why did you disable harfbuzz?

Comment: @peppe On qt5 it works as expected without harfbuzz, but it seems that on Windows you can't easily enable harfbuzz